# Centralizar elementos de um SVG

Tags: svg, css, css-centering

Olá, tenho um `<g>` dentro de um SVG e gostaria de centralizar o seu conteúdo, basicamente seria assim:

```
+-----------------+       x-----------------+
|  X              |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 | ----> |        x        |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
```

Podem me ajudar?

Código de ajuda

```xml
<g id="content" transform="translate(28.000000, 50.000000)">
    <text id="header" font-family="Varela Rounded, sans-serif" fill="#334152">
        <tspan x="65" y="35" font-weight="bold" font-size="16">COMPROVANTE</tspan>
        <tspan x="174" y="2" opacity="0.8" font-size="10">
            {{transacao?.registered | date:'dd.MM.yyy'}} | {{ transacao?.registered | date :'HH:mm'}}
        </tspan>
    </text>
<g>
```

No caso eu gostaria de centralizar esse `<text>` dentro do `<g>`

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta com um [mcve]

Comment: É bem grande, mas ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou te dar um passo a passo que vai te ajudar. Detalhe sua tag `<g>` não está fechada corretamente tem que ser `</g>`

**1** - Alinhe o `<g>` no centro do SVG usando `transform="translate(201, 151)"` repare que os valores 201 e 151 são o centro aproximado do `viewbox` do SVG que no seu caso é `viewBox="0 0 403 302"`

**2** - Alinhe o texto no centro do próprio eixo usando o `text-anchor="middle"` do próprio SVG https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor isso vai fazer com que o texto sempre fique centralizado independente do número de caracteres.

**3** - Ajuste o valor Y do subtítulo para ele ficar abaixo do texto principal `y="15"`

**OBS:** Apenas coloquei uma borda no SVG para vc visualizar melhor como ficou a centralização:

```css
svg {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="403" height="302" viewBox="0 0 403 302" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="content" transform="translate(201, 151)">
        <text text-anchor="middle" id="header" font-family="Varela Rounded, sans-serif" fill="#334152">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" font-weight="bold" font-size="16">COMPROVANTE</tspan>
            <tspan x="0" y="15" opacity="0.8" font-size="10">
                texto dinâmico
            </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```