# Texto em SVG HTML

Tags: html, svg

Possuo o seguinte código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

Teria alguma forma de colocar um texto dentro desse SVG ?

tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<textPath xlink:href="#OdyssGlobalArea1">
    MENU
</textPath>
```

Comment: O que você entende por "texto dentro do SVG"?

Comment: Tem sim, mas o que vc pretende?

Comment: @hugocsl Estou começando a utilizar SVG "aprendizado" e gostaria de saber até onde eu conseguiria manipular/utilizar um SVG.
Tentei colocar um texto mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Acho que vc está complicando as coisas, olha a resposta que eu deixei ai, e sobre TextPath leia aqui  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346357/como-fazer-anima%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-svg-ou-css-de-um-texto-andando-pelo-caminho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo é só colocar a tag `<text>` dentro do SVG, ela vai funcionar como um elemento com `position:absolute`, e vc vai precisar usar o `X` e `Y` para posiciona-lo, ou então vc pode usar `Transform/Translate` direto dentro do SVG. Recomendo que leia essa outra resposta que tem uns pontos sobre alinhamento e `text-anchor` tb [Centralizar elementos de um SVG](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343212/centralizar-elementos-de-um-svg/343409#343409)

Olha ai eu peguei o próprio texto que estava la dentro e coloque a tag de texto e o X/Y

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    <text x="0" y="40">Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @GabrielSilva sem problemas meu caro, não deixe de dar uma olhada no links que citei. Olhe aqui tb que tem muito material didático lá http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/index.html

Comment: Com certeza, mais uma vez obrigado.